# CPP-like feature for Python text processing

Tags: python, c-preprocessor

I have a python script that emits text files which are inputs to a 3rd-party black box application, and it constructs the files according to input data and command line options. Depending on command line options a couple of these big text files differ only in one or two lines, I'll create an example below.  Sadly, there is no good way to implement this on the black-box side of things, it only accepts straight directives, and `if` statements inside its inner loops make it *very* slow.

What I would like is to have a python module that contained the text with some `cpp`-like directives to choose the right lines in the text file it outputs. E.g., a file like `blackboxText.py`:

```
__txt="""
...
bunch of code
...
#if OPTION1
<command sequence one>
#else
<command sequence two>
#endif
...
bunch of code
...
"""

def get(options):
    return(cpp(__txt,options))
```

What I **do not** want is to actually have to run `cpp`, I need to stick to python as the only executable in this stage.

I don't need the whole suite of 'cpp' commands like '#include', but it's not bad if it's complete.  And it doesn't have to be `cpp`, it could be anything approximately similar in functionality.

Is there a Python module that can parse `cpp`-like directives like this in a text block?

Comment: No, there is no such thing. Instead of looking for cpp features in python, you should decide: use python the way python is used, or use cpp.

Comment: I welcome suggestions on a pythonic way to achieve the end I need: a large text file with just a couple lines that vary based on options

Comment: That is easy: use `if` instead of `#if` (not in the middle of a string, of course, use string formatting for that)

Comment: There are Python implementations of the C Preprocessor cpp - is that an option?

Comment: Or use templates, such as those used for generating html in web servers.

Comment: CPP is a separate program to manipulate text. Just run it on your program then use its output file as your input file.